# update form field with js but not showing in submitted data

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, cakephp

Experimenting with JsHelper in CakePHP 2.0, I got a Request method to update the value of a form field with the results of an AJAX call - so far, so good. However, on inspecting the form field it says:

```
<input type="hidden" id="JobsPartUnitcost" name="data[JobsPart][unitcost]">5.55</input>
```

but when I copied it and first pasted it above it said

```
<input type="hidden" id="JobsPartUnitcost" name="data[JobsPart][unitcost]"></input>
```

and when I submitted the form the value was empty. Why is the browser showing the value but the underlying DOM not registering it?

Using Mac/Safari, CakePHP 2.0, JQuery

***EDIT***
As requested here is form data dump

```
    Array ( [JobsPart] => Array ( [job_id] => 1 [company_id] => 4 [part_id] => 2 [qty] => 3 [unitcost] => ) )
```

and here is AJAX code

```
$this->Js->get('#JobsPartPartId')->event('change',
    $this->Js->request(
        array(
            'controller'=>'JobsParts',
            'action'=>'getPart'
        ),
        array(
            'update'=>'#JobsPartUnitcost',
            'async' => true,
            'method' => 'post',
            'dataExpression'=>true,
            'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                'isForm' => false,
                'inline' => true
            ))
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: How you are getting the value from the hidden, can you past your code of the ajax post?

Comment: The copy/paste sub-question may have to do with how the browser shows page source - most browsers (can't speak to safari specifically) will show you the original page source as downloaded, not the "current state" source, when you do a "View Source".  Can't speak to the other question without more info - care to post the JS that's setting the form, and a dump of what's being sent to the server?

Comment: OK. I have found a workaround but I won't post it as an answer unless no one else finds one. In my static view I now have just <td id="part"></td> where the input field was. My Ajax call now updates '#part' and my dynamic view (the one called by the controller ajax action) now outputs the whole field - <?php echo $this->Form->input('unitcost', array('type' => 'text', 'value' => $part['Part']['costamount'])); ?>. Ugly but it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I have found a workaround and no one else seems to have found a direct solution.

In my static view I now have just `<td id="part"></td>` where the input field was. My Ajax call now updates '`#part`' and my dynamic view (the one called by the controller ajax action) now outputs the whole field - `<?php echo $this->Form->input('unitcost', array('type' => 'text', 'value' => $part['Part']['costamount'])); ?>`. Ugly but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the value attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" value="YOUR VALUE HERE" name="data[Etc][field]" />
```

You don't wrap a value in input tags.

Comment: Having the value wrapped like `<input>Value</input>` will render in the browser as the value because it sees it as a traditional tag.

Comment: I thought as much. So, based on the code I have now shown, how would I do that?

Comment: How are you generating the hidden input fields?

Comment: You need to use `<?php $this->Form->hidden('fieldname', array( 'value' => valuehere ) ); ?>`

Comment: The value is generated from an Ajax call (see edit) after the page has loaded. 'value' => 'valuehere' won't make a difference (will it?).

Comment: OK I have +1's this answer as it is true, but it is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->Js->get('#JobsPartPartId')->event('change',
 $this->Js->request(
    array(
        'controller'=>'JobsParts',
        'action'=>'getPart'
    ),
    array(
        'success'=>'$("#JobsPartUnitcost").val(data)',
        'async' => true,
        'method' => 'post',
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
            'isForm' => false,
            'inline' => true
        ))
    )
)
```

);

Comment: did u attend to this line? 'success'=>'$("#JobsPartUnitcost").val(data)',