# How to set value to input field with cakephp 2.x?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp

I need to set a value to a input text field in cakephp 2.x.

Description:
I have a select field where I display a list of articles, depending of the article that the user has selected I have to set the price of this article in a input text field (readonly).

I am using javascript. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function alerta(a){
           var price = ?//something in a function within my controller.
           document.getElementById("AperturaArticuloPrecio").value = "price";
    }

</script>
```

My input fields:

```
echo "<table><tr><td>";
echo $this->Form->input('articulo_id',array('onChange' => 'alerta(1)'));
echo "</td><td>";
echo $this->Form->input('cantidad',array('type' => 'text'));
echo "</td><td>";
echo $this->Form->input('precio',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly'));
echo "</td><td>";
echo $this->Form->input('total',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly'));
echo "</td></tr></table>";
```

I understand that 'a' variable in my javascript code must to be the name of the article, and I need to get the price of this article using mi controller, but I don't know how to call the controller using javascript.

If you need more details tell me. Thank you.

---

Update:

I changed my javascript code for the next code:

```
    <?php
        $this->Js->get('#AperturaArticuloArticuloId')->event('change', '
                //alert($( "#AperturaArticuloArticuloId" ).val());
                $( "#AperturaArticuloPrecio" ).val($( "#AperturaArticuloArticuloId option:selected" ).text());
                //Here something to call my function in my controller
            ');
        echo "<table><tr><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('articulo_id');
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('cantidad',array('type' => 'text'));
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('precio',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly'));
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('total',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly'));
        echo "</td></tr></table>";
    ?>
```

So I could get the index of the article was selected and its content, I just need to send this values to a function in my controller. How could I do this? - Do I need to use AJAX, Json or something else?

In my controller I have this function but I don know how to access it:

```
public function getPrice($id = null) {

    $options = array(
        'fields' => array('Articulo.precio'),
        'conditions' => array('Articulo.id' => $id));
    $price = $this->Articulo->find('list', $options);

    echo $price;
}
```

I'll be grateful for a link! XD

Comment: You need set a value , why you are using javascript here ? 
echo $this->Form->input('total',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly' value = 'myvalue'));

Comment: Use onchange function and call your results through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Well I was searching here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html and I mixed with [update form field with js but not showing in submitted data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228616/update-form-field-with-js-but-not-showing-in-submitted-data)

My solution was:

```
    <?php
        $data = $this->Js->get('#AperturaArticuloArticuloId')->serializeForm(array('inline' => true));

        $this->Js->get('#AperturaArticuloArticuloId')->event(
            'change',
            $this->Js->request(
                array(
                    'action' => 'getPrice', 
                    'controller' => 'articulos'
                ),
                array(
                    //'update' => '#AperturaArticuloPrecio',
                    'success' => '
                        $("#AperturaArticuloPrecio").val(data);
                        //More javascript code here
                    ',
                    'data' => $data,
                    'async' => true,    
                    'dataExpression'=>true,
                    'method' => 'POST'
                )
            )
        );

        echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();

        echo "<table><tr><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('articulo_id');
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('cantidad',array('type' => 'text'));
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('precio',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly'));
        echo "</td><td>";
        echo $this->Form->input('total',array('type' => 'text','readonly' => 'readonly'));
        echo "</td></tr></table>";
    ?>
```

and in my controller:

```
public function getPrice() {
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $options = array(
        'fields' => array('Articulo.precio'),
        'conditions' => array('Articulo.id' => $this->request->data['AperturaArticulo']['articulo_id']));

    $price = $this->Articulo->find('list', $options);

    $article_selected = implode(",", $price);

    echo "$".$article_selected;
}
```

Thanks everybody for help me!